# build chromium on Mac then I got cannot execute binary file

Tags: c++, chromium

I am trying to build Google Chromium on a Mac.
To get Chromiumum I did the following steps:

1. `fetch chromium` on a Google Cloud Ubuntu Server.
2. `git fetch origin tag <tag>` on the server.
3. Zip the downloaded source and then download the zipped source to my local machine
4. Unzip the source on my local machine.

This process is need due to bad network connection in China which meant `git clone` can experience packet loss.

To build, I did the following steps:

1. `gclient sync`
2. `gn gen out/Default`
3. `autoninja -C out/Default chrome`

When doing this I get the following error;

```sh
[1/48575] CC obj/third_party/libwebp/libwebp_dsp_sse41/dec_sse41.o
FAILED: obj/third_party/libwebp/libwebp_dsp_sse41/dec_sse41.o 
../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang -MMD -MF obj/third_party/libwebp/libwebp_dsp_sse41/dec_sse41.o.d -D_LIBCPP_HAS_NO_ALIGNED_ALLOCATION -DCR_XCODE_VERSION=1220 -DCR_CLANG_REVISION=\"llvmorg-12-init-11462-g418f18c6-1\" -DCOMPONENT_BUILD -D_LIBCPP_ENABLE_NODISCARD -D_LIBCPP_DEBUG=0 -DCR_LIBCXX_REVISION=375504 -D__ASSERT_MACROS_DEFINE_VERSIONS_WITHOUT_UNDERSCORES=0 -D_DEBUG -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DWEBP_NEAR_LOSSLESS=0 -DWEBP_DISABLE_STATS -DWEBP_REDUCE_SIZE -DWEBP_REDUCE_CSP -DWEBP_EXTERN=extern -I../.. -Igen -I../../third_party/libwebp -I../../third_party/libwebp/src -msse4.1 -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector-strong -fcolor-diagnostics -fmerge-all-constants -fcrash-diagnostics-dir=../../tools/clang/crashreports -mllvm -instcombine-lower-dbg-declare=0 -fcomplete-member-pointers -arch x86_64 -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -D__DATE__= -D__TIME__= -D__TIMESTAMP__= -Xclang -fdebug-compilation-dir -Xclang . -no-canonical-prefixes -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -gdwarf-4 -g2 -isysroot ../../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.10.0 -ftrivial-auto-var-init=pattern -fvisibility=hidden -Xclang -add-plugin -Xclang find-bad-constructs -Wheader-hygiene -Wstring-conversion -Wtautological-overlap-compare -Werror -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wunguarded-availability -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-c++11-narrowing -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-undefined-var-template -Wno-psabi -Wno-ignored-pragma-optimize -Wno-implicit-int-float-conversion -Wno-final-dtor-non-final-class -Wno-builtin-assume-aligned-alignment -Wno-deprecated-copy -Wno-non-c-typedef-for-linkage -Wno-max-tokens -std=c11 -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -c ../../third_party/libwebp/src/dsp/dec_sse41.c -o obj/third_party/libwebp/libwebp_dsp_sse41/dec_sse41.o
/bin/sh: ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang: cannot execute binary file
```

I'm working on this over 5 days, pls help me.

Comment: Have you installed `clang`

Comment: To build chromium on MacOS you need Apple Xcode and xcode command line tools installed. Have you done this. Also what version of MacOS are you trying to build Chromium on?

Comment: of course I installed clang and Xcode, last week I built the chromium successfully, but the version is wrong, so I try it again and fetch to older version, but I got the error

Comment: So did you switch to a different tag then try to rebuild Chromium again? You should run `gclient sync` again after switching to a new version cause dependences will change based on the version of Chromium used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, I found a solution.

I remove src/third_party/llvm-build directory, then `gclient sync` again.
It will download executable clang program.

thx everybody.